# Context Aware BCS Model for Search Crawling in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, bcs, sql, bdc

I have an external SQL data source that I would like to include in SharePoint search crawling with a BCS/BDC model.  As it stands, SharePoint sees this data independently of the SharePoint site structure.  This data is related to specific SPWeb's.  What I would like is for SharePoint to correlate this external data with the SPWeb it is associated with so that when end-users search in a SharePoint site, the external data returned in the search results is relative to the SharePoint site they are currently viewing.

Can I accomplish this with a BCS model?  If not, what alternative methods could I use to expose this data for search crawling and have it correlated to the SPWeb it belongs to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, I found that if I set the DisplayUriField (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg294165.aspx) of the item to specify a page within the SPWeb (which I did with a _layouts application page, ie. http://site.local/web/_layouts/myitem.aspx?id=xxx), SharePoint will return the item in the search results when searching inside that SharePoint web.